# How to get iPhone Landscape from Unity 3D

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, landscape-portrait

My problem is after building form Unity and deploying onto my iPhone the screen looks like so.(see pic)

On the Unity Game tab everything works fine, why does it change on the actual device?[image]

How can i get the screen to play in LANDSCAPE? 
Also: How is it possible to enable multi-touch in Unity 3D so that on an iPhone you can touch the screen with two fingers and get multi responses?

Thanks in advance, any code that you need just ask.

Note: In player settings i have it set to Landscape Left

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation of the screen:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html

Comment: That changes touch also and didn't work for me anyways. I'm not sure why